# How long can a UI-related object stay usable?

Tags: java, android

I guess this is a lame question, I can't even make up a proper subject! Here is what I'm trying to do under Android:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    ...
    AskFilename ask = new AskFilename();
    ...
}
```

Here, `AskFilename` class will present a user interface to let the user enter a filename. However, the `ask` object will be out of scope once the `onCreate()` method returns. So this means there will be no reference to `ask` any more (assuming inside `AskFilename` class, I did not assign its `this` pointer to any other variable), and so GC will, sooner or later, "collect" it. When this happens, if the user hasn't OK'ed the dialog box, the code in `AskFilename` is already unavailable and therefore the system will crash. Is my understanding correct?

(I can't think of a way to experiement with this idea, because I don't know how to make GC do its job. It seems that GC kicks in only when it wants to! Is there a way to make it do its job?)

If the above is correct, then what is the proper way to new a UI-related object? I know I can make evrything inside `AskFilename` static, or I can make `ask` a static vairable and assign it to null when it's done. But is there any other way? Or, the idea itself is bad in the first place?

(Does it make any difference if AskFilename is an "inner" class of the Activity? Like MyActivite.AskFilename.)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can just put the declaration  `AskFilename ask;` outside of the method declaration, i.e. as a member of your class. Then you initialise it with `ask = new AskFilename();` in your onCreate method.

However, the thing to know is that your constructor probably won't look like that. Every Android UI component contains a callback (a reference) to the thing containing it. You typically do this by passing a `Context` to the constructor of a UI component- inside an Activity, the context is usually just the Activity itself, so you just use the `this` keyword. e.g:

`TextView tv = new TextView(this);`

However you construct your AskFilename dialog, I expect you will need to pass the Context down to its components. So your constructor will probably need to take a Context argument:

```
 ask = new AskFilename(this);
```

Additionally, your Activity will hold references (implicitly) to all of its UI components, and dialogs it shows with `onCreateDialog()` So your object won't get picked up by the GC. 
It gets these references either when you call setContextView or make the dialog.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, like you said, I do need a reference to Activity in the constructor. Just for the sake of discussion, this only guarantees that every UI view AskFilename creates have a reference to the Activity, but not AskFilename. That is, AskFilenameis still an orphan in this case (assuming I'm not making `ask` a class member of Activity as you suggested, which does work for me). Am I right?

Comment: Perhaps, but in practice you can only make it appear on the screen if you call setContentView on it (somehow), attaching it to your existing layout, or your make it appear by creating it as a dialog, both of which give the Activity a reference to your object.